# How to iterate and add a new field to an array in JSONata object?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonata

I have JSON object where I have a key **policyList** whose value type is array. Inside **policyList** there is another array under the key named **product**. There is **amount** field present in each object of the array **product**.

I want a flag inside **policyList** array based on the amount value i.e., if amount = '0' for all the products, then set flag to true else set flag to false.

This is the JSON I have:

```
{
    "admissionDate": "2023-10-04",
    "claimCaseId": 123,
    "dischargeDate": "2023-10-20",
    "hospital": "abc",
    "policyList": [
        {
            "policyNo": "P1",
            "product": [
                {
                    "amount": 1000,
                    "productName": "Product 1"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 1200,
                    "productName": "Product 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "policyNo": "P2",
            "product": [
                {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "productName": "Product 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "reasonCode": ""
}
```

This is the expected JSON:

```
{
    "admissionDate": "2023-10-04",
    "claimCaseId": 123,
    "dischargeDate": "2023-10-20",
    "hospital": "abc",
    "policyList": [
        {
            "policyNo": "P1",
            "flag": false,
            "product": [
                {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "productName": "Product 1"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 1200,
                    "productName": "Product 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "policyNo": "P2",
            "flag": true,
            "product": [
                {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "productName": "Product 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "reasonCode": ""
}
```

I tried using the [Transform operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform) but was not able to add the evaluation logic for the flag.

Comment: Which programming language are you expecting?

Comment: I need a JSONata expression not in any programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to look for the Transform operator. This should solve your case:

```
$$ ~> |policyList|{"flag": $sum($.product.amount) = 0}|
```

Check it out on the [Stedi Playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJylUs1qwzAMfhVjctggLY7TXQbbpbsUSuk9yUFzvNYQxyFOYCPOnn127TYLYyOwk2R9PxKSswxr1beM4xjz96blWgtV2wcYYhIbh7xGKMdQSnGBXqDjOX60JUpoukrIimxyHHsWq0DILWi%2BKx0noWkASqHZGdoT%2Fymn5CY%2FK92IDipPgFd2QxpVCfaxF7pzWOaKCA0%2BTPhBeeUxCcIAtqrs2XflTO1JIFVfXzgJISSeg8HhADIMf%2FQFZBtNzDFe4k6Xu9OZ%2BzUtfHLt9vsW6H%2B2sHjI9M8hXSjCEVsOWtVbVQYHJxztF4si9PmMzHRjM%2BT4rYKTo0W6l3fROrRf%2BwHv0RMio7FaZahJzQYXMX7AxRddY8aM)

Answer (score 2):

See working playground example [here](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJy1k0FrgzAUx79KCIVe7IixuwjbDt1lMErv6uEtpm1AjSQKHcZ99sXGqVtb1hWWS%2FLe%2B78f%2FxeSKMJa1opx7GF%2BKBXXWsjCBmCI8e3exAWyK8aQ5uJYfIaKxzi0KUposPDJgixj7H3pWAYiX4HmL2mn8mkwlFKh2R7Ujp8iKJkg9lKXooLMSeCNTWqlzAR7fxW66qqRS3erGY9T5Vo6ysYfIBOJkmnNfpIuEMc2yGVdHLt8Qoh3SdbT15D3w25cAlkrpz3tGc41DugtDuhZB99TyRhOvf12z%2FQ%2F7vmGEYM%2FjuiOyfDQFActi5VMe26Ha%2B2HmKGPR2TGZ2hQM99msJuHqPcSJXfOeaec5XBAD4igJ1SpmqMQbSHTvDUWJQ01gVnixMP3OPkEBVrhYA%3D%3D)

```
$ ~> |policyList| {'flag': product[].amount ~> $max = 0 }|
```